# C# how to remove repeating words and phrases out of a string globally

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

We have a service that translates voice to text and it does a horrible job at times.  I am seeing sentences that repeat word and phrases, here are some examples:

1. I, I I will go
2. , you know, (used over and over)
3. Over use of "like,"
4. I mean, my first, my, my first, my first weekend down there, we went downtown, downtown Newark

Is there a good way to remove these or clean it up at all?  I've tried to look and haven't really seen anything that works well.  I'm guessing others ran into something like so hopefully there's a solution here.

Comment: Removing immediately duplicated words is pretty simple. But removing duplicated multi-word phrases is a lot harder. Removing a bunch of "like" instances sprinkled throughout your text would require a "like"-specific rule. You need to get a more specific set of rules (like for your "I, I I" example)

Comment: You could use GPT-3 or ChatGPT-3 for such cleanup tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code
[image: ![enter image description here]
[image]

```
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public string test(string before)
        {

            var WithPunc = before.Split(" ").ToList();
            var punctuation = before.Where(Char.IsPunctuation).Distinct().ToArray();
            var listWithoutPunc = before.Split().Select(x => x.Trim(punctuation)).ToList();

//start compare single duplicate word.
            int i = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                if (i+1==WithPunc.Count() ) break;

                if (listWithoutPunc[i] == listWithoutPunc[i + 1])
                {
                    if (WithPunc[i].Length >= WithPunc[i + 1].Length)
                    {
                        listWithoutPunc.RemoveAt(i);
                        WithPunc.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listWithoutPunc.RemoveAt(i+1);
                        WithPunc.RemoveAt(i+1);
                    }
                }
                else i++;
            }
//start compare double duplicate word.
            i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (i + 3 == WithPunc.Count()) break;

                if (listWithoutPunc[i]+ listWithoutPunc[i+1] == listWithoutPunc[i + 2]+ listWithoutPunc[i + 3])
                {
                    if (WithPunc[i+1].Length >= WithPunc[i + 3].Length)
                    {
                        listWithoutPunc.RemoveRange(i,2);
                        WithPunc.RemoveRange(i,2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listWithoutPunc.RemoveRange(i+2, 2);
                        WithPunc.RemoveRange(i + 2, 2);
                    }
                }
                else i++;
            }
            var after = String.Join(" ", WithPunc.ToArray());
            return after;
        }
```

I get 2 lists first, one with punchuation for keeping the breakpoint, one without for easily comparing. 
[image]
[image]
Then filter the single word first. Compare with the word using list without punchuation. And remove the both lists.(to keep index the same). The condition is to remove `my,` rather than `my`  .After this we get a list like 
[image]
Then we can start the double duplicate removing.Then we get the right result.

You can create what ever length combination filter with this logic. I just write 2.

It's harder to tell the scenario of overuse of 'you know' or 'like' if they are not adjacent. Long sentence such as `Do you know how to do that? If you know please help me` could be wrongly deleted. It will need something like machine learning.